# How can I become invisible (or) turn off my network share folders .. from my network workgroup (Windows XP)?

Tags: network-shares

My network folder "Scheduled Task" is appearing in my workgroup. I don't want it like that.

- I want myself to become totally invisible in my workgroup.
- I don't want to share (any of my files) with anyone, over network.

How can I do it? Can I be totally invisible or password protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of things you can do:

- Turn off *Client for Microsoft Networks* in the Properties of your network connection. This will prevent others on that network from seeing your computer or accessing your computer by its computer name. (that is, `\\\computer` will stop working, but they can still access you by IP address).
- Turn off *File and Printer Sharing* and then nobody from that network will be able to access your share even if they use your IP address.
- Type *services.msc* into Start -> *Search programs and files* box (Start -> Run for XP or older), press Enter. In the new window, find the item *Server* and set its *Startup type* to *Manual*.
- To prevent others from seeing your shares without a password, disable the *Guest* account from User Accounts in Control Panel. (Note that people who have the same user name and password combination on their computers as yours will still be able to log-in. For example, if your company uses the user name "User" and password "123" on every computer, then all people will be able to access each others files as if they're logged in locally.)
- Fiddle with local group policy and file permissions

Comment: How can i "Turn off File and Printer Sharing" ? Is the 3rd bullet is for that?

Comment: @Alvin The _File and Printer Sharing_ option is in the same Properties page as _Client for Microsoft Networks_. You can disable this on a per connection basis or disable the _Server_ which is global.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Computer Management (right click My Computer>Manage) and navigate to `System Tools>Shared Folders>Shares`. Right click your share (it will be different from my screenshot), and click "Stop Sharing".

[image]

Comment: When i click `Stop Sharing`, there is appearing: `The IPC$ share is required for the server service to operate, and cannot be deleted.`

Comment: You need to read the list and pick the one that you actually want to stop sharing...It will not end with a $. It should be the name of that share you browsed to. If you have further questions, post a screenshot and I can tell you exactly.

Comment: In other words, I only showed you the where and how, you have to use your eyes to pick the one that you have an issue with, but leave ALL the ones with $.

Comment: I have only 1 line there (IPC$ like the one you've selected above).

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of what you think is being shared, because if it is not in that list, it is not being shared.

Comment: The only sharing folder is "Scheduled Tasks". I think this is system default share folder. What i want is "not" to share anything. If possible, i don't wanna let anyone see me (my computer name) inside workgroup. If it can't, i wanna strict with Password.

Comment: You can't really not share anything as you saw when you tried to remove that system share. As far as passwords go, as long as you have secure passwords for your user account and the administrator account, and any other accounts you have, you should be fine. I am not sure how you think they would access your data otherwise.

Comment: Ok so final words that "How can do for that if anyone browse my pc (like "\\mypc"), i want to ask password."

Comment: To be honest, I thought I understood in the beginning, but it is less clear. Other than the scheduled tasks, does anything else show up when you do \\yourpc from a different computer? You probably can stop sharing of scheduled tasks, but it is apparently more complex than just using the Computer Management MMC.

Comment: Yeah, you aren't gonna be able to block \\mypc without cutting off your ability to communicate with other computers.  You are better off using a firewall to block protocols, rather than trying to mess with the IPC$, which could be disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the firewall approach.  Block ports 135 - 139.

Keep in mind you can't block EVERYTHING.  The same channels that your computer uses to communicate with other computers, like your router, have to stay open.  So thus, there are always going to be ways to see your computer.  For example, I had a user block the ARP protocol cause he was paranoid. Not even two seconds later, he was calling me from home cause he couldn't VPN into his office. . .

Comment: Thanks for your alternative approach. Please what will be the results if i block ports 135-139? Any drawbacks?

Comment: Yeah, you lose NetBIOS resolution and the ability to share files using a network share.  The advantage of using a firewall versus the above methods is that the side effects are more predictable.  For example, the Server service will break programs that depend on it, even if they aren't sending traffic over the network.  Using a firewall method will prevent traffic over this port, but keep the service alive for programs that may depend on it locally.